# SendGrid email with Ruby client or Rails extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Just switching to SendGrid and am very surprised (and incredibly confused) at the various methods and libraries used to send email.

The official ruby client by SendGrid builds an email and request, and then [constructs a POST request](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/lib/sendgrid/client.rb#L25..L39) to send that data over to their smtp endpoint.

However Rails uses `ActionMailer`, and there exist other gems like [sendgrid-actionmailer](https://github.com/eddiezane/sendgrid-actionmailer) and [sendgrid-rails](https://github.com/PavelTyk/sendgrid-rails) to extend functionality to Rails.

What does `ActionMailer` actually do here? I know you can configure `smpt_options` and then call `mail(..)` inside your mailer to send email. Does that just construct a similar POST request and send it? If so, is it guaranteed to be the same one constructed by the official ruby client (i.e. is there a standard to this?)

Answer (score 1):

ActionMailer is just the basic Rails email sending framework. Out of the box it's capable of making SMTP email calls and a service like SendGrid is a drop-in solution for that.

It can also be configured to use a delivery method like a JSON API, which is a popular alternative, or something even more exotic, like dumping it in a job queue.

The library to use depends on what features you want to use. If you just need a quick fire-and-forget system, the SMTP default method might work for you. If you need something with more control, the API-based one might be better.